# Apply Bootstrap 4 DropDown Style for asp.net DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4

Can anybody help me with code showing how to apply bootstrap 4 drop down style for asp.net drop down list. tried to apply bootstrap-select but it is not working.

Site.master

```
<link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="<%= (Request.ApplicationPath + @"js/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js").Replace(@"//", @"/") %>"></script>
<script src="<%= (Request.ApplicationPath + @"js/tether.min.js").Replace(@"//", @"/") %>"></script>
<script src="<%= (Request.ApplicationPath + @"js/bootstrap-select.min.js").Replace(@"//", @"/") %>"></script>
<script src="<%= (Request.ApplicationPath + @"js/bootstrap.min.js").Replace(@"//", @"/") %>"></script>
```

In my .aspx Page :

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlStudentDepartment" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="selectpicker">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Select a Department" Value=""/>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="MCA" Value="MCA" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="IS" Value="IS" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="CS" Value="CS" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="EEE" Value="EEE" />

                </asp:DropDownList>

var dropDown = $('#<%= ddlStudentDepartment.ClientID %>');

    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log('Inside Ready');
        dropDown.selectpicker();

    });
```

I am not able to see any DropDown Menu Items. As shown below:

```
[![No Items Displayed][1]][1]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you tried? share your code here

Comment: I have updated my Question with code. I tried only bootstrap-select. It did not work. Tried adding Bootstrap 4 DropDown Classes. Not understanding where to add dropdown-menu classes as ListItem does not have CssClass Property.